# Convert word file to Pdf using Php

Tags: php

I want to convert Word files to PDF using PHP.
 basically its work fine for me on localhost. but not working on live 
 server.
    My code is

```
  $word = new COM("Word.Application") or die ("Could not initialise

  Object.");
  $word->Visible = 0;
  $word->DisplayAlerts = 0;
  $rand = (rand(100000,100000000));
  $word->Documents->Open('Test.docx');
  $word->ActiveDocument->SaveAs('files/'.$rand.'.doc');
  $result=
  $word->ActiveDocument-ExportAsFixedFormat('files/'.$rand.'.pdf', 17, 
  false, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, true, true, 2, true, true, false); 
  $word->Quit(false);
  unset($word);
  echo "done";
```

it's working fine for me on localhost but giving me the following error on a live server
**This page isn’t working** 
multibizservices.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: It could be a folder permission problem. Did you check permissions on live server?

Comment: i don't know how to check i am looking for php.ini file

Comment: Can you try debugging it line by line? For example, yout comment out everything after the 7th line, upload, and check if it's giving an error. Repeat, until you find which line causes the error, then it's easier to pinpoint to source of the error.

Comment: @ALFA how to check permission on live server cpanel

Comment: yes i checked it line by line

Comment: If you checked line by line in what line it gives you the error?

Comment: i comment all the code except first line and giving the same result 

This page isn’t working multibizservices.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Basically it stuck on this 
$word = new COM("Word.Application") or die ("Could not initialise Object.");
they don't know COM

Comment: Is the live server Windows or LAMP?

Comment: From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/com.requirements.php): *`COM` functions are only available for the Windows version of PHP.*